# How to remove unnecessary single quotation marks (') from column names in a R data frame?

Tags: r, quotation-marks

unfortunately I have got colnames, which all have additional single quotation marks like here:

```
x <- data.frame(c(11,21,31),c(12,22,32),c(13,23,33))
colnames(x) <- c("'A'","'B'","'C'")
```

So my question is, if I can get rid of those "'" for my entire data frame? 
Preferably not retyping the colnames, and using tidyR code?
Thanks!

Comment: `colnames(x) <- gsub("'","",colnames(x))`

Comment: @Onyambu you should Include your comment as an answer. Its the simplest way of answering the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(stringr)

colnames(x) <- str_remove_all(colnames(x), "'")
```

That should do it

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
    x %>% 
       rename_all(~str_remove_all(., "'"))
```

If you want a pipe

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks - Great library - I was worried I would have to use gsub! What a relief ;-)

Answer (score 3):

In `base R`:

```
names(x) <- gsub("'", "", names(x))

x
   A  B  C
1 11 12 13
2 21 22 23
3 31 32 33
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `trimws` in `base R`

```
names(x) <-  trimws(names(x), whitespace = "'")
x
#   A  B  C
#1 11 12 13
#2 21 22 23
#3 31 32 33
```